# How to add resource dependencies in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have created a gcp kubernetes cluster using terraform and configured a few kubernetes resources such as namespaces and helm releases. I would like terraform to automatically destroy/recreate all the kubernetes cluster resources if the gcp cluster is destroyed/recreated but I cant seem to figure out how to do it.

The behavior I am trying to recreate is similar to what you would get if you used triggers with null_resources. Is this possible with normal resources?

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name               = "marcellus-wallace"
  location           = "us-central1-a"
  initial_node_count = 3


resource "kubernetes_namespace" "example" {
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = "example-annotation"
    }

    labels = {
      mylabel = "label-value"
    }

    name = "terraform-example-namespace"

    #Something like this, but this only works with null_resources
    triggers {
       cluster_id = "${google_container_cluster.primary.id}" 
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#resource-dependencies?

Comment: I have indeed looked at that, and from what I can see that argument will only affect the order the resources are deployed in. If in the above plan I changed a variable in `google_container_cluster` that would cause it to be redeployed, terraform wouldn't automatically pick up that the namespace would also need to be redeployed, even if the `depends_on` argument was there. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, you don't need to specify any explicit dependencies. They will be set automatically because you have `cluster_id = "${google_container_cluster.primary.id}"` in your second resource.

In case when you need to set manual dependency you can use [depends_on](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#depends_on-explicit-resource-dependencies) meta-argument.

Comment: There is no `triggers` option in the `kubernetes_namespace` resource, I posted the one above as an example of the behavior I want to achieve. As far is I can see there is no similar argument in the `kubernetes_namespace` resource (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/namespace.html). 

The `depends_on` argument from what I can tell and from my testing is only relevant in regards to the order the resources are deployed in on the cluster. If I were to recreate the GCP cluster the `depends_on` argument would not pick up the fact that the namespace also needs to be recreated.

Comment: Oh, I got your point.
Then you can try to move your in-kubernetes resources to separate module and configure kubernetes provider in this module:

```
variable "endpoint" {}
provider "kubernetes" {
  host = "https://${var.endpoint}"
  ...
}
```

I did not test it, but I guess it can works.